# c#, Limit custom array to only show the highest values

Tags: c#, arrays, limit

I'm trying to write a program that takes the name and hight of five persons and the displays the name and hight of the person with the highest height-value. If there are several persons that share the highest hight-value they should all be displayed.

At the moment I am able to print out the values of my custom array but I have no idea of how to limit the print out to only show the highest hight-values.

/Mattias

```
    public ButtonForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    /* *************************************************************************** */

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button_Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Person[] persons = { new Person { Name=TextBox_Name1.Text, Height=int.Parse(TextBox_Height1.Text)},
                             new Person { Name=TextBox_Name2.Text, Height=int.Parse(TextBox_Height2.Text) },
                             new Person { Name=TextBox_Name3.Text, Height=int.Parse(TextBox_Height3.Text) },
                             new Person { Name=TextBox_Name4.Text, Height=int.Parse(TextBox_Height4.Text) },
                             new Person { Name=TextBox_Name5.Text, Height=int.Parse(TextBox_Height5.Text) } };

        IEnumerable<Person> query = persons.OrderBy(person => person.Height);

        foreach (Person person in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", person.Name, person.Height);
        }

    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

To get highest people, simply use:

```
int highest = persons.Max(p => p.Height);
var query = persons.Where(p => p.Height == highest);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
int maxHeight = persons.Max(p => p.Height);

var tallestPersons = persons.Where(p => p.Height == maxHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
    foreach (Person person in query) {
        if(person.Height == query.First().Height) {
             Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", person.Name, person.Height);
        }
    }
```